# Google Rich Snippets Testing Tool "This page does not contain authorship or rich snippet markup" error

Tags: seo

i am trying to test the below snippet using google snippets testing tool but all i am getting is "This page does not contain authorship or rich snippet markup" and it getting very annoying any ideas what might be the problem??

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Organization">
<span itemprop="name">Linas</span>
Located at<span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Address">
<span itemprop="street-address">Plaza Hotel</span>,
<span itemprop="region">Hamra</span>,
<span itemprop="locality">Beirut</span>,
<span itemprop="country-name">Lebanon</span>,
</span>Phone: <span itemprop="tel">9611751244</span>.
<a href="http://www.linaslb.com" itemprop="url">http://www.linaslb.com</a>.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try using **schema.org** as your itemtype source instead of data-vocabulary.org. I pasted the below into http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets and it seems to work.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
<span itemprop="name">Linas</span>
Located at<span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Address">
<span itemprop="street-address">Plaza Hotel</span>,
<span itemprop="region">Hamra</span>,
<span itemprop="locality">Beirut</span>,
<span itemprop="country-name">Lebanon</span>,
</span>Phone: <span itemprop="tel">9611751244</span>.
<a href="http://www.linaslb.com" itemprop="url">http://www.linaslb.com</a>.
</div>
```

Comment: thank you eywu. i realized  that this morning after a fresh start with my day :). cheers